# Before subtitle tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm working on a `tcolorbox` and trying to make the subtitle the same as the title

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems, listings, breakable, most, skins}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable,empty, 
coltitle=blue, colback=white, left=0mm, right=0mm, boxrule=0mm, boxsep=0mm, 
colframe=green,colbacktitle=white, 
before title ={\textcolor{green!70!black}{Respostas: }}, title= \textcolor{gray}{Montante},
before upper={\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\bfseries\textcolor{blue}{\alph*)}}},
    subtitle style = {
      frame empty,
      colback = white,
      coltext = gray,
      top=1em}]

   Para 2 meses o montante está em $1102,50$. Contudo para 3 meses o montante está em R$\$ 1557{,}62$. 
   Portanto, se houver a correção em períodos fracionários, serão necessários menos de 3 meses e mais do 
   que 2 meses. 

   \tcbsubtitle{Dívida no cartão}

   Podemos utilizar a tabela para calcular o montante em cada mês a partir de R$\$10.000{,}00$.

   \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The thing is, I tried using the key `before subtitle` just like `before title`, and tried putting `before title` in `subtitle style`, but it seems neither work. Is there another way I can ensure the text `\textcolor{\currentcolor}{Respostas: }` appears before every subtitle?

[image: This is what I get]

I can get this result using two `tcolorbox`, but I wish I could do this using a subtitle.

[image: This is what I want to achieve]

Comment: add `colupper=...` inside `subtitle style`. This options fixes subtitle color.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. What I want is the text appearing before every subtitle, not just the color.

Comment: As the subtitle box is like another `tcolorbox` and title color changes with `colupper`, some text can be added inside subtitle box with a `before upper` option added inside `subtitle style`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: Please make your MWE runable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.